# Entity Relations from freebase dump

Tags: entity-relationship, freebase

I want to dump all entity-name-pair with a relation.

Example :

```
subject predicate object
<freebase/ns/g.11bc7__xnw>  <freebase/ns/people.place_lived.location>   <freebase/ns/m.02_286>  .
```

Freebase in above line refers to url of freebase website.
I extracted all triplets which have mid in subject and object, then I took the predicate as the relation.

For the above example my code will output something like this:

```
entity pair : g.11bc7__xnw , m.02_286
relation : people.place_lived.location
```

I have two issues:

1. when I ran my code on freebase dump I got 14887 relations but the actual number of relations in freebase are more than 25,000 .
2. for some mid's, there is no property name or alias. (`/type/object/name,
   /common/topic/alias`)

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: example : <freebase/ns/g.11bc7__xnw> <freebase/ns/people.place_lived.location> <freebase/ns/m.02_286> .

Answer (score 0):

Well, some relations to not point to a mid, but to a basic value:

`<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.date> "2001-02"`

And that's basically the entire measurement_unit domain.

Then, the mids that don't have name and alias sound like cvt's (compound value types) which are artificial nodes that hold a complex relationship (eg. node to node + time).

So I think you should account better for measurements, booleans, dates, etc. and cvts.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
For my work, I don't want these type of compound value types.